# How do i delete a whole dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
mylist = [{"a" : 1, " b" : 2}, {"c" : 1, "d" :2}]
```

My list goes something like this. How would i delete the entire dictionary which contains the key 'a'?

Comment: Is this always the first dictionary? What if there are two dictionaries with a key "a"?

Comment: `{d for d in mylist if 'a' not in d}`?

Comment: Lets try first with 'if there is only one dictionary with the key' a'.' I'm a beginner in python and would like to move slow and understand well as i go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `filter` to solve this problem:

```
mylist = [{"a" : 1, " b" : 2}, {"c" : 1, "d" :2}]
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: "a" not in x, mylist))
```

Output:

```
[{'c': 1, 'd': 2}]
```

Regarding your recent comment, to delete a dictionary with value "apple":

```
mylist = [{"a" : "apple", "b" : "orange"}, {"c" : "pineapple", "d" : "mango"}]
final_list = list(filter(lambda x:"apple" not in x.values(), mylist))
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanx, i have a follow up question,

If my list goes something like this, 

mylist = [{"a" : apple, "b" : orange}, {"c" : pineapple, "d" : mango}] 

How would i delete the dictionary which contains the word "apple"?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I searched google a lot to get a clear explanation and an answer. Now i know. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You may use *list comprehension* to create a new list with the `dict`s without the `'a'` key as:

```
>>> mylist = [{"a" : 1, " b" : 2},{"c" : 1, "d" :2}]

>>> [d for d in mylist if 'a' not in d]
[{'c': 1, 'd': 2}]
```

If it is *must* to delete the elements from the original list, then you may do something like:

```
>>> mylist = [{"a" : 1, " b" : 2},{"c" : 1, "d" :2}]

#                           v Iterate over the copy of the list,
#                           v    so that the change in index after the 
#                           v    deletion of  elements in the list won't 
#                           v    impact the future iterations
>>> for i, d in enumerate(list(mylist)):
...     if 'a' in d:
...         del mylist[i]
...
>>> mylist
[{'c': 1, 'd': 2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you said that

> I'm a beginner in python and would like to move slow and understand well as i go

So I'm focussing on the explanation steps instead of just giving you the solution straight away.

The easiest way to check if **one** dictionary contains a specific key is to use `in`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
>>> 'a' in d
True

>>> 'c' in d
False
```

Likewise you can check if it's not a key in a dictionary with `not in`:

```
>>> 'c' not in d
True

>>> 'b' not in d
False
```

Since you're dealing with a list of dictionaries you need to iterate over it. With Python you can iterate over each element with `for`:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'a': 10, 'b': 20}, {'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
>>> for subdict in list_of_dicts:
...     print(subdict)
... 
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
{'b': 10, 'c': 20}
```

So you basically just need to combine the `for` loop with an check if the key is `in` the subdict. However it's not a good idea to modify whatever you're currently iterating over, so you could create a new list to store the dictionaries you want to keep:

```
>>> keep_these = []
>>> for subdict in list_of_dicts:
...     if 'a' not in subdict:
...         keep_these.append(subdict)
...
>>> keep_these
[{'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
```

There is an even easier way to do this in Python: A list comprehension. Moinuddin Quadri already presented it but just to repeat it:

```
>>> [subdict for subdict in list_of_dicts if 'a' not in subdict]
[{'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
```

This is essentially exactly like the `for` loop I used above but it's shorter and faster.

Comment: very descriptive, and well explained (+1)

Comment: Thankyou. Well explained and easy to understand!